# Flex URLRequest and .NET authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, apache-flex, authentication, authorization

can I make role based authorization when sending requests to an ASP.NET MVC backend system. I am calling action methods and expecting JSON results, however, some action methods are decorated with the [Authorize] attribute, others require some role privileges to be present. I certainly hope that passing authorization data with every request is possible

Answer (score 0):

Unless the methods are designed to accept login information as parameters, you would typically have to login to the system by posting a form to the "login" action -- typically /account/login -- and from then on send the authorization cookie that you receive back with each new request to validate who you are.  There are a lot of ways to configure the backend, though what I've described is the typical way.  Fortunately, [URLRequest](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLRequest.html) has a way to specify that you want the HTTP stack to manage cookies for you, so this should be reasonably seamless from your end.  **NOTE:** I've never used FLEX, I'm just going by the documentation.

Comment: Is the cookie set automatically? I am approaching the LogOn action method with right credntials, but all the default one does is to redirect me to the index method. No cookie seems to be created.